# How to free memory when dequeuing from a linked list?

Tags: c, queue, malloc

I'm using `malloc()` function in order to create a queue in C, the problem is that when I use the `dequeue()` function I leave an unreferenced element. I have to use this function lots of times per second, so I would like to know which is the best way to handle it or if there is a better way than using `malloc()`. These are the two functions:

```
void enqueue(struct Queue *q, char c){
//adds an element to the queue
    struct Member* m = malloc(sizeof *m);//in order to make m global    
    if(!m){ perror("malloc");exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
    if(q->length == 0){

        m->ch = c;
        q->first = m;
        q->last = m;

    }else{    
        m->ch = c;
        q->last->next = m;
        q->last = m;
    }   
    q->length++;
}

char dequeue(struct Queue *q){
//returns the first element of the queue an delete it
    char c;
    if(q->length >0){
        q->length--;
        c = q->first->ch;
        q->first= q->first->next;
        //CLEAR THE UNREFERENCED VARIABLE
    }
    return c;
}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

These are the structs that I'm using:

```
typedef struct Queue{
      int length;
      struct Member *first;
      struct Member *last;
}Queue;

typedef struct Member{
      char ch;
      struct Member *next;
}Member;
```

Comment: Why don't you free it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the `unreferenced variable` to a `temporary variable` first so that you can `free` it after changing the first node of the queue.

```
//returns the first element of the queue and delete it
char dequeue(struct Queue *q){

    struct Member* temp = q->first;;
    char c;

    if(q->length >0){
        q->length--;
        c = q->first->ch;
        q->first= q->first->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    return c;
}
```

You can check more about `free` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/).